# weird lighting of a cone with eevee ( and cycles too )

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, eevee-render-engine

super noob question here.

I have created a very simple scene with just a cone, a light and a camera. The cone has a default white material and I selected "shade smooth" for it.

The light is the default light and is placed at the bottom of the cone and a bit in front and to the side of it.

I am not trained as an artist, so I don't have more than a vague idea about how the end result should be. In my understanding the light on the cone should have at least a more round shape.

Obviously there is something I am missing here. The default settings produce the results below.

I am using blender 2.90.1 on a Mac.

Is there anyone who knows what my problem might be and how to solve it?

Please let me know if there is any more info about the scene that I need to write in order to get help.

Thanks :-)

When I render the scene with eevee I get weird artefacts:[image: This is what I get with eevee]

When I render it with cycles it is a bit better but still weird:
[image: This is what I get with cycles]

Comment: So far I know is, shadow could be blocky even it has shaded smooth. Maybe try add a subsurf, although it will mess the cone? I’m not sure about it

Comment: I did some testing, and cones (even cylinder with the top scaled to a small value) don't play nice with shade smooth.  I recommend more vertices or holding edges and subdivision.  Refer to this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194494/smooth-shade-a-cone